# "GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START/END" and "PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently learning the new "System versioned temporal table" introduced in sql server 2016. However, I'm having a bit of a hard time getting my head around the exact meaning and use of "GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START/END" and "PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME", both of which are required by system versioned temporal table.

Could someone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees
(
    empid INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    empname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    salary NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL,

    sysstart DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,

    sysend DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,

    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(sysstart, sysend),
    INDEX ix_Employees CLUSTERED(empid, sysstart, sysend)
)

WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeesHistory)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Temporal Tables in SQL server 2016**

This is an amazing new feature in `SQL Server 2016` and later.

In Quick points, What is temporal tables ?

- Introduced in 2011by ANSI/ISO for SQL
- IBM DB2 & Oracle 10g,11g and 12c were early adopters.
- Designed to keep a full history of data changes and allow easy point in time analysis.
- Every temporal table has two explicitly defined columns, each with a `datetime2`data type.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)

> A system-versioned temporal table must have a primary key defined and
>   have exactly one PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME defined with two datetime2
>   columns, declared as GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START / END

So The primary key for A `system-versioned` table (consider this as a nickname of temporal table) defined and have exactly one `PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME` defined with two datetime2 columns for allowing easy point in time analysis or **Time Travel** ([As Mr.Borko Novakovic said at Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Temporal-in-SQL-Server-2016)), declared as `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START / END`

**References:**

- [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)
- [Creating a System-Versioned Temporal Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590957.aspx)
- [Temporal in SQL Server 2016 - Video.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Temporal-in-SQL-Server-2016)

Comment: You link to MS Connect is no longer valid as they've deprecated that area and not kept the information as an online archive. Could you include the relevant point directly in your text, or find an updated link? (I've edited out the link for now)

Comment: The "GENERATED ALWAYS" statement just indicates that the values in the two DATETIME2 fields you specify to define the system period are ALWAYS generated automatically be SQL Server rather than being populated manually.

Comment: "This is an amazing new feature" - It's a nice feature, but there are loads of drawbacks and gotchas - for example, we can't exclude columns from being tracked, zero-change `UPDATE` operations still cause history rows to be added, making schema/table-design changes is very painful, it's almost impossible to edit history, etc.

Answer (score 1):

System versioned Temporal table is using unit of time for tracking any row changes with the use 2 column of type DateTime2 ( start and End Time). By using DateTime2 , SQL get exact time irrespective of timezone.

SYSTEM_TIME is used as PERIOD by checking start and End Time and this field also using for select statement to get history records from transaction and history tables.

```
SELECT * FROM [Your_Table]
    FOR SYSTEM_TIME    
        BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2015-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
```